# An error occurred while installing jekyll-sitemap (0.11.0)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, octopress

I try to build an Octopress in my PC, but when I executed `bundle install` in git bash. The results showed

> Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - D:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-sitemap-0.11.0/spec/fixtures/_posts/2016-04-01-ih
>   [image]

I don't know how to fix it , please help, thank you!